# Probability of a pair of face cards question

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Hey guys little bit stuck on this probability question any help would be great.

"A regular deck of playing cards contains 52 cards, you are randomly dealt 7 from the the 52. What is the probability of you receiving two pairs of face cards of different ranks (e.g. $J-J, \ K-K$) and any three cards whose ranks are different from those of both pairs?"

So far I have worked out that the probability of receiving one pair is ${_3}C_1\times {_4}C_2$ and I think the probability of the 2nd pair will be ${_2}C_1\times {_4}C_2$. I'm a little confused on the 2nd part tho, my guess is that it will be something like ${_{44}}C_3$. I know this will all be over ${_{52}}C_7$.

So my worked out answer is $\Large{\frac{{_3}C_1\times{_4}C_2\times{_2}C_1\times{_4}C_2\times{_{44}}C_3 }{ {_{52}}C_7}}$. If this is slightly incorrect any hints in the right direction would be great.

Comment: I don't know what qualifies. Would $2$ each of J, Q, K be good?  Whatever answer one chooses, the $\binom{44}{3}$ is not right.

Comment: Amended, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two answers**

Firstly, you have to take note that *order does not matter* for choosing the ranks of the  pairs.

Secondly, normally, such questions imply *exactly* two pairs. but the way it is worded, it could mean *at least* two pairs, which becomes more complex. I'll solve for both.

*Exactly two pairs*:

After you have chosen the ranks for the pairs, 11 ranks remain for choosing "singles"

$\dfrac{{3\choose 2}{4\choose2}^2{11\choose 3}{4\choose 1}^3}{52\choose 7}$

*At least 2 pairs:*

To the numerator for *exactly two pairs*, add the part for *exactly 3 pairs*
:

${3\choose 3}{4\choose 2}^3{10\choose 1}{4\choose1}$

Comment: Ah okay I see where I went wrong, I never took in to account that the order would not matter. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You are welcome :)